# NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot, postgis

I want to add PostGIS to my Spring Boot project, so I added the following dependencies:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gmoika</groupId>
    <artifactId>GmoikaApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>GmoikaApi</name>
    <description>GMoika project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernatespatial</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial-postgis</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>spymemcached</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
     <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- add JBOSS repository for easy access to Hibernate libraries -->

    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have the following error:

```
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

    Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
     resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.c
  lass]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
                at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
                at com.gmoika.GmoikaApiApplication.main(GmoikaApiApplication.java:18)
                ... 6 more
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/MetadataBuilder
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)


... 22 moreenter code here
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.MetadataBuilder
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 28 m
```

Maybe its due to Hibernete versions. Error occured when I add PostGIS dependencies to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change the dependency of `hibernate-core` in **pom.xml** to `5.0.4.Final`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank for response, i change it but now i have the following error
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project GmoikaApi: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for groovy.lang.Closure not found

Comment: Could you please open another thread for this or post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: try adding the dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.11